# Get specific result entry with adhoc query

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I have an inventory of about 10 hosts.
On all I want to check if a specific file exists. So I do:

```
ansible -m stat -a 'path=/the/file' all
```

And then I get a load of output because on most servers this file does actually exist.

But I only care for `stat.exists` for each host.

## Is there any possibility of displaying only a specific entry of the result set per host?

And I do not want to use a playbook. This is specifically for ad-hoc queries.

Comment: Pipe to [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) would do the job if you manage to get output in JSON. Unfortunately `export ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json` doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

For such a trivial test, you can emit a marker string that allow you to filter out all the other junk to just see the host that matches:

```
ansible -m raw \
   -a 'if [[ -e "/the/file" ]]; then echo "FOUND: $HOSTNAME"; fi' \
   all 2>/dev/null | grep ^FOUND
```

Comment: This does solve this particular problem, but does not answer the question.

Comment: Your question was "Is there any possibility of displaying only a specific entry of the result set per host?" which this does; the middle ground is to use `ansible --one-line` and feed that though `awk -F"|" '/inode/{print $1}'` to grab the host which brought back an inode entry, and the only pure-ansible way is what Vladimir suggested and find out why `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK` doesn't work for `AdhocCLI`